# What is a .pex file (in related to Urho2d sample)?

Tags: c#, xml, tags, urhosharp

This is what I read in:

https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples/blob/master/FeatureSamples/Core/25_Urho2DParticles/Urho2DParticle.cs[Urho2D][1]

Line 90:

ParticleEffect2D particleEffect = cache.GetParticleEffect2D("Urho2D/sun.pex");

Does anyone have a clue on how to produce one of these particle effect and put it into a .pex file for the Urho2d engine to load?

I know it can be opened in an XML file known as ParticleEmitterConfig tag, but that is all I could find in this content.

Thanks

Comment: Need sample of xml.  The link you provided you needs a login.

Comment: https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples/blob/master/FeatureSamples/Core/25_Urho2DParticles/Urho2DParticle.cs

Comment: Found the pex files are this url : https://github.com/xamarin/urho-samples/tree/master/FeatureSamples/Assets/Data/Urho2D